# Need to show popup page in testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

My issue is I have a one web page with three button. If I click on new button one popup page should open. But in my case it's successfully hitting the new button but popup page is not visible. So please guide me how can i show a popup page after clicking on new button.
Thanks

I have tried
setNativeDialogHandler(() =>)
Click('#newButton') but it didn't work

Comment: I need a simple example with a page and a test to be able to help you. Please share this example. If you don't want to share it here, you can do it in [the team repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A%20bug&template=bug_report.yaml).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can't share you the pic only I can say consider the example of registration of employee where when user clicks on new button to add new employee at that time after hitting new button pop up page should open with employee detail like name address and all other detail here just need to open that pop up page which contains the employee details. My testcase is getting passed but after hitting new button pop up is not visible

Comment: It isn't necessary to share your real project. Try to create a simple sample. Use [this guide](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402636/faq/general-info#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue) for better understanding.